# Git: Fork vs submodules vs Subtree

Tags: git, github

I have an ecommerce project that is made up of 3 parts, an `admin dashboard`, an `api(core)`, and a `storefront(frontend)`, the `dashboard` and the `api` will be taken from open source repositories and the `storefront` will be developed from 0 on its own repository, now my question is, what is the best way to handle this on git? create `submodules` with the open source repositories and my frontend repository, or `fork` the open source repositories and work on it and add the frontend.

I want to make some changes in the open source repositories, but also keep it synchronized with the changes that can be made in the original repo.

#### EDIT 1

I'll use docker-compose to run the services..

[image]

#### EDIT 2

[This](https://github.com/mirumee/saleor-platform) is the open source repository that I want to use as template to develop my ecommerce, the diference is that I want to develop the storefront with other technology...

Comment: If you are making changes in the submodules, then your submodules are forks.  So using submodules means you're doing both.  IMO, avoid submodules at all costs.  They are never worth the headaches they cause.  They (appear to) allow you to avoid a proper deployment method, and are far more trouble than they're worth.

Comment: @WilliamPursell So the recomended road its to fork the open source repository and add my work(storefront) on it?

Comment: I wouldn't add the storefront to the other repos.  As you described previously, create your work in its own repo.  Use the other projects, but use a deployment mechanism other than submodules.  How you do that will depend on the framework/language of the system you're building.  It may be as simple as extracting an archive of the other projects.  `git submodules` can do that for you, and it is seductive, but it would be better to find a more robust mechanism.

Comment: @WilliamPursell can you explain this better, "How you do that will depend on the framework/language of the system you're building". I'm using Django(Python) for API and React for dashboard and storefront. What do u mean with `robust mechanism.`

Comment: Your Git repo is where you keep the code, not where you run it. When you want to run it, you have to install/deploy it. If this was all Python, for example, your deployment could all be based on `pip install`. You can have your own fork of Api and Dashboard, your own Storefront (obviously), and install/deploy each repo in a environment that sees all three, where you run your tests and eventually do the same thing for production. Git doesn't have to be aware of the dependencies between the three projects, only your deployment/installation procedure needs to be aware of them.

Comment: @WilliamPursell I understand your point, but I still have some doubts, take [this repository](https://github.com/mirumee/saleor-platform) as an example, it has 3 repositories, one for the API, one for the dashboar and one for the storefront and use git modules and dokcer-compose to to deploy all the services. what i want is just the dashboard and api of this repository, and replace the storefront with my own development. then i must fork the whole repository and simply replace the storefront module with mine? or is there a more efficient/recomended way? Do you understand where I'm going?

Answer (score 6):

> ... what is the best way to handle this on git?

*Best* questions are usually opinion questions, and hence off-topic on Stack Overflow.

What we can say from a technical perspective is this:

- A *fork* is just a clone with some features.  The features are determined by the hosting system: GitHub forks, Bitbucket forks, and so on are not exactly 100% identical in terms of added features, because each hosting provider wants to get you to use *them* and not the others.  But they all start by cloning.
- A *submodule* is just a Git repository.  What makes it a submodule is that some *other* Git repository says: *clone this Git repository, then checkout out commit _____* (fill in the blank with a hash ID).  The *other* Git repository—the one with the clone-and-checkout instructions in it—we call a *superproject*, and *this* Git repository, we call a *submodule*.

  Submodules have a bunch of annoyances that come with them.  The biggest one is implied by the blank above.  The superproject Git repository is *required* to list the *exact commit hash ID* to use in the submodule.  Any changes made *to* the submodule require making a change to the superproject as well: you must make a new commit in the superproject so that you list a new and different submodule hash ID.

  You *cannot* have the superproject refer to the submodule by *branch name*.  You *can* put a name into the superproject, but the superproject Git mostly doesn't *use* the name.  When it goes to command the submodule to get some commit, it does so by raw hash ID.  So you're stuck dealing with raw hash IDs.  There is nothing wrong with this, it's just something to be aware of.

  Submodules typically have the secondary annoyance that, to build the software, you need the superproject *and* all of the submodules.  Any glitch in *getting* the submodules and checking out the right commits holds everything up.  Such glitches are not *common*, but they do occur.  Since the superproject doesn't contain the submodule, the superproject can be small: in fact, a superproject that has no code of its own—that simply refers to submodules—can be *tiny*.
- A *subtree* is neither of the above.  When using `git subtree`, you take two plain (not-specially-handled) Git repositories.  They each have their own branches and everything as usual.  Now and then, you run `git subtree` with a subcommand: `split` to split something up, or `merge` to combine something back in.  (The `pull` and `push` commands are `merge` and `split` in disguise, followed by a separate second Git command.)

  Remembering that all Git repositories are primarily collections of commits, the `split` subcommand lets you take a collection of commits (usually less than *every commit*, but it could be *every commit*)   in the "bigger" Git repository, and modify and extract some of those commits so they'll fit in the "smaller" Git repository.  Meanwhile the `merge` subcommand takes the commits in the smaller repository, matches them up against an earlier split, figures out what's new since then, and "embiggens" them to fit back into the larger repository and adds them to that larger repository.

  What this means is that both the smaller and larger repositories are self-contained, which was also true with the submodule approach, but that the *larger* repository is *so* self-contained that it *never needs the smaller repository at all*.  It just has it available, *if* it has it available, to do more split-and-merge operations.  *Everything* is in the larger repository.  You don't have to get or use the smaller repository at all, ever, unless you want to do a new split and/or merge.  You can give the smaller repository out to others, while keeping the large one private; changes people make to *add to* the smaller repository, you can try to take back later with `git subtree merge`.

  Unlike submodules, this means the larger ("superproject"-ish) repository *contains everything*.  So there's never any problem with the submodule not being available but, unlike submodules, the "superproject" is always the biggest thing around.  You are not *referring to* some other Git repository's commits.  You *contain* those commits, as transformed by the `merge` subcommand to fit into your own "superproject"-ish repository.  So *your* repository can only be tiny if the *whole project* is tiny (in which case, why did you bother with subtrees?).